# Extended slice in python?

Tags: python, slice

I am trying to write a BitArray class, and it would be nifty to have something like numpy's array, `x[i:j:k] = val`.

How would I write this in Python? Not with the `__setslice__`, right? Because that only takes three arguments and I need one to take four.

Comment: What four arguments do you want to pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__setslice__` is deprecated - you'll want to use `__setitem__` with a slice argument.

Note that, per the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), slices can only be done in the following  syntactic forms: `a[i:j:step]`, `a[i:j, k:l]`, or `a[..., i:j]`. The colon-based syntax is used to define a single slice object, but as the second example shows you can have multiple slice arguments (they get passed in as a tuple of slices).

Here's an example which prints the `key` argument, to see its form:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
>>>     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
>>>         print key
>>> 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a[1:1] = 1
slice(1, 1, None)
>>> 
>>> a[1:1:1] = 1
slice(1, 1, 1)
>>> 
>>> a[1:1, 1:1] = 1
(slice(1, 1, None), slice(1, 1, None))
```

Comment: There's some sample code at the bottom of http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html that is actually still useful for these purposes; it (more or less) documents the otherwise-undocumented `indices` method of `slice` objects, without which implementing a fully-general `setitem` on slices is fairly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

`__setslice__` is deprecated, see the [Python 3 changelog](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods):

> `__getslice__()`, `__setslice__()` and `__delslice__()` were killed. The syntax `a[i:j]` now translates to `a.__getitem__(slice(i, j))` (or `__setitem__()` or `__delitem__()`, when used as an assignment or deletion target, respectively).

Similarly, you can pass a step value to `slice()` which means the syntax `a[i:j:k]` translates to `a.__getitem__(slice(i, j, k))`.